# Platform error when deploying Experience Bundle (sites.data.store.ConcurrentEditDetectedException ORA-20612)

Tags: deployment, experience-cloud, experience-bundle

We were having a 7 dwarf error when trying to deploy a Experience Bundle to a Sandbox. We were using metadata api (using sfdx) to deploy an update to an existing community in a sandbox

```
sites.data.store.ConcurrentEditDetectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-20612:                                                                                                                                             
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.SITEDEVCOMPONENT", line 684                                                                                                                                                                                          
ORA-06512: at line 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
SQLException while executing plsql statement: {call SiteDevComponent.update_components(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}(0DM0Q0000008Rn7, EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, true, EXCLUDED)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We found that, when we entered the site in the target org, this popup appeared

[image: popup message]

After clicking reload and publishing the site, we were able to deploy the site

Hope it helps anyone in the same situation